# Unable to compile using make test(windows)

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, command-line

While trying to compile my test plugin I encounter this error. At the moment i can't figure out why it isn't working. I m using a windows and try to execute the command in OSGeo Shell.

I typed in OSGeo Shell: make test and got:

```
pyrcc4 -o resources_rc.py  resources.qrc
make: pyrcc4: Command not found
make: *** [resources_rc.py] Error 127
```

From the looks of it, I do not have the make command installed?

Comment: From the looks of it, you do not have the `pyrcc4` command installed.

Comment: how can i install pyrcc4?

Comment: Not sure exactly. I just found this http://www.qgistutorials.com/de/docs/building_a_python_plugin.html